# Can't configure Docker in JetBrains IDE

Tags: docker, ide, jetbrains-ide

I have installed Docker Desktop. hello-docker works fine from my cmd, but I can't configure Docker in my GoLand IDE, I get the following error:

> Cannot connect to the docker daemon at `npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine`. Is the docker daemon running?

Honestly, I don't know what are local path and vm path parameters, but I can't even google something relevant about these parameters.

[image]

If I ignore this error my images just don't build in the IDE. Can somebody help with that?

I checked my Docker in cmd, works fine, Docker Desktop works too. While trying to configure, Docker Desktop is launched for sure.

Comment: What do you have in `settings > build, execution, deployment > docker > tools` does it point to your docker.exe file?

Comment: Yes it does, And to docker-compose.exe too